# How to make Image Gallery app look same on ALL different screen sizes?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridlayout

I'm developing the app like Image Gallery with images fetching from web. All images have same width `200px` and height `280-300px`. I use `RecyclerView` with `Adapter.ViewHolder` and `GridLayoutManager` with count of spans = 2. Images loading with `Picasso` library.

item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tile_picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="260dp"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
```

On my device `5" 720x1280` it's look fine.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrDm0.jpg)
But when I launch app on other devices, it's look not so good...
On `5.5" 1080x1920` there are extra margins between images.
On old `3.7" 480x800` there is only one span, width bit more, than half-screen size.
I suggest, because `android:layout_height="260dp"` hardcoded.
So, how can I get same look on different devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you implement a custom view, and in `onMeasure` get the screen width, and then pass half of the width:

`setMeasuredDimension(width/2, height);`

This will guarantee that on any device you'll have an image on half the screen.

Comment: Thanks for idea. Instead I've just tried `@Override
    public TopViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.main_tile_item, parent, false);
        int width = (parent.getMeasuredWidth() / 2) - 4;
        int height = (int) (width * 1.5);
        view.setMinimumHeight(height);
        
        return new TopViewHolder(view);
    }` And seems it works!